# REST API auth conception

Tags: security, rest, restful-authentication

I wanted to have inputs on this REST API authentication conception.

I am not sure to understand how to design the user authentication & the client authentication.

If the user is not logged, should I link the tokens to an "anonymous user" ?

Without SSL, if someone intercept the clientId & clientSecret/publicToken & accessToken, he could pretend to be an user or the client ?

[image: auth conception]

Comment: With no SSL, intercepting the `client id + client secret` part would be even worse.

Comment: OK, but in case of a webapplication, ```the client id + client secret``` would be exposed. So how can I trust the client?

Comment: Hi, would you mind telling me where you found this graphics or did u create them self?

Comment: Hi, I created them with draw.io, pretty nice tool ;)